# Extend a modules database table

Tags: database

I would like to extend the schema of another module's ("Rooms") database table.

I have my own module for alterations of that module (specifically the Rooms-module)

Rooms has "Options" with Name, Value..etc...

I want to add "Description" to Options.

My question:

is it possible to alter the database-table of another module..??

How would I start to change this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a litle confused about your goal, but taking your question literally as *I would like to extend the schema of another module*, and assuming by extend you mean alter and not inherit from, then yes, it's pretty straightforward.

First of all, implement [`hook_schema_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_schema_alter/6) so that Drupal knows about the change you're going to make to the table:

```
function MYMODULE_schema_alter(&$schema) {
  $schema['rooms']['foo_table']['new_column'] = array(
    // ...
  );
}
```

Then add an update hook to your module's install file to physically add the field to the table, e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_update_7100() {
  $schema = drupal_get_schema_unprocessed('rooms', 'foo_table');
  db_add_field('foo_table', 'new_column', $schema['new_column']);
}
```

It would also be advisable to implement `hook_uninstall()`/`hook_disable()` to remove that column from the table when your module is no longer active. Leaving it there probably won't hurt anything, but for the sake of cleanliness it's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could with `hook_schema_alter` for example. but I wouldn't recommend it.

Rather I would try to use something like your own database table and an entity reference or use the [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) module to store your own fields. Then use `field_extra_fields` to attach your custom fields onto the Room forms or display output.

Comment: If the base table isn't an entity, I think it's fine to alter the schema (assuming you clean up after yourself when the module leaves). If it was an entity table then yeah, bad idea all day long